# Problema de python: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Tags: python, base-de-datos, tkinter

```
def Restar(self):
conn = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost', 
                       database='ventas'
                       ,user='root',
                       passwd = '')
cursor= conn.cursor()
        
idp=int(self.miIdp.get())
        
stock=int(self.mistock.get())
cantidad=int(self.micantidad.get())
total=int(stock-cantidad)
sql = "update producto set stock='%d' where idproducto = '%d'"
args=(total,idp)
try:
    cursor.execute(sql%args)
    conn.commit()
except:
    messagebox.showwarning("ADVERTENCIA","Ocurrio un error al actualizar el registro,verifique conexion con base de datos")
            pass
```

Error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\lib\tkinter_init_.py", line 1883, in call return self.func(*args) 
File "C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\POO\PY\CRUDsalida.py", line 307, in actualizar self.Restar() 
File "C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\POO\PY\CRUDsalida.py", line 329, in Restar idp=int(self.miIdp.get()) 
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Comment: Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\POO\PY\CRUDsalida.py", line 307, in actualizar
    self.Restar()
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\POO\PY\CRUDsalida.py", line 329, in Restar
    idp=int(self.miIdp.get())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: podras añadir una explicacion?, esta bien que muestres el codigo, pero necesitamos saber el contexto de la situacion

Comment: Supongo que estás trabajando con Entrys. Si los entrys están vacios y la función Restar se ejecuta, por supuesto que te dará ese error. Despues de todo, '' (que es lo que devuelve un entry cuando está vacío) no se puede considerar un numero entero.

Comment: gracias me hiciste darme cuenta de mi error lo habia puesto asiself.Limpiar()
            self.mostrar() self.Restar()